# Strange date format in database

Tags: t-sql, datetime, hex, converters

I have some very strange looking 18 character alphanumeric datetimes in a SQL database, they seem to be using Hexadecimal?

I can find out what the dates are through the application which uses them, but I was looking for a way to convert them via a query. Do you know how I would convert these with TSQL?

`000B3E4Bh01F2D947h` - `29/05/2018 09:04:52`
`000B3E0Dh03A16C1Eh` - `23/05/2018 10:22:26`
`000B3E4Eh0248C3D8h` - `01/06/2018 10:38:43`
`000B3E4Eh0249B449h` - `01/06/2018 10:39:44`

I assume the date and time are separated as below, but I don't know to convert the individual parts if anyone can help with this? Thanks!!

`000B3E4Eh` (date) - `0249B449h` (time)

(The dates are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format)

Comment: As mentioned many times on other questions before, storing DATETIME data in non `DATETIME` datatypes is never a good idea

Comment: @Mazhar I suspect OP is well aware of that...

Comment: If you can enter some data by our own, try to use "magic numbers": try january 1st, 1900, 00:00, january 2nd 1900, 00:00, january 2nd 1900 01:00 etc .... to find how the data are stored.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately these are generated by the system, and so I do not have any facility to enter the magic numbers.

Comment: The best I can get is these two date times which are two seconds apart

Comment: 000B3E54h0221CBFEh - 07/06/2018 09:56:09

Comment: 000B3E54h0221D2A2h - 07/06/2018 09:56:11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hex values are separated as you have assumed (with the `h` used as a delimiter) and represent integer values to add to a baseline `date` and `time` value.

Using your `000B3E54h0221CBFEh - 07/06/2018 09:56:09` value this translates as:

Date portion:  `000B3E54`
Integer Value: `736852`

Time portion:  `0221CBFE`
Integer Value: `35769342`

These integer values are then added as days to the date `0001/01/00` (which SQL Server can't handle, hence the +/-1 below) and milliseconds to `00:00:00` respectively, which you can see working in this script:

```
select convert(int, 0x000B3E54) as DateIntValue
    ,dateadd(day,convert(int, 0x000B3E54)-1,cast('00010101' as datetime2)) as DateValue

    ,convert(int, 0x0221CBFE) as TimeIntValue
    ,cast(dateadd(millisecond,convert(int, 0x0221CBFE),cast('19000101' as datetime2)) as time) as TimeValue

    ,cast(datediff(day,cast('00010101' as datetime2),'20180607')+1 as binary(4)) as DateHexValue
    ,cast(datediff(millisecond,cast('20180607' as date),cast('2018-06-07 09:56:09.342' as datetime2)) as binary(4)) as TimeHexValue
```

Which outputs:

```
+--------------+-----------------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+
| DateIntValue |          DateValue          | TimeIntValue |    TimeValue     | DateHexValue | TimeHexValue |
+--------------+-----------------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+
|       736852 | 2018-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 |     35769342 | 09:56:09.3420000 | 0x000B3E54   | 0x0221CBFE   |
+--------------+-----------------------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Note the judicious use of `datetime2` values to ensure the right amount of milliseconds are output/returned, as SQL Server `datetime` is only accurate to the nearest 3 milliseconds.

Comment: That's amazing @iamdave! you sir are a genius! Thanks so much!